# Repeated elements counting for Sql datatables queries

Tags: sql, database, count

I have 2 tables: an Order table and an orderDetails table.
   I have written a inner join:

```
  SELECT Order.id
  FROM Order
  INNER JOIN orderDetails 
   ON Order.id=orderDetails.id
```

I have got the output as:

```
   id
  100
  100
  100
  101
  101
```

From the above data, I want the count of each record output as:

```
  id  count
  100  3
  101  2
```

How would I do this?

Comment: If any answer helped you, it can be accepted by clicking the green tick next to it.

Answer (score 2):

```
Select OrderId , Count(*) as [Count]
from OrderDetials
Group By OrderId
```

OrderId will be a foreing key column referencing Order.Id column of Order Table

If your orderDetails.id references Order.id column This will be the query.

```
Select id , Count(*) as [Count]
from OrderDetials
Group By id
```

Comment: +1 for spotting the redundant join. This isn't strictly the same, though it's only a problem if there are details with missing orders (which is very unlikely, of course).

Comment: Yes. that's right. In case when there can be orders not having details, those can be missed. +1 for spotting the exceptional case.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT o.id, COUNT(*)
  FROM Order         o
  JOIN orderDetails  od  ON o.id=od.id
 GROUP BY o.id
```

Comment: Join is not required. There has to be a foreign key column in orderDetails table to be able to have relations between the two table. That should do the work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the COUNT aggregate and the GROUP BY clause.

```
SELECT Order.id, COUNT(DISTINCT orderDetails.id)
FROM Order 
INNER JOIN orderDetails ON Order.id=orderDetails.orderId 
GROUP BY Order.id
```

It also looks like you need o alter the join condition slightly.

Answer (score -1):

Use Group by

```
SELECT Order.id, count(*) as Count
FROM Order
INNER JOIN orderDetails 
ON Order.id=orderDetails.id Group by Order.id
```